# What event does createorder emit on Opensea?

Tags: nft, opensea

What on-chain event is emitted once an order has been submitted to Opensea with creatorder() function?
I cannot see any events on the wallet's etherscan page or any transaction.

Comment: Can you link to the `createorder()` function? Could not find anything on their GitHub - https://github.com/search?q=org%3AProjectOpenSea%20creatorder&type=code

Comment: here you go https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/seaport-js/blob/cb447e9378881e6d5c98a364d4276318d325108f/src/seaport.ts#L186

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a off-chain method  so you could not see any info on chain.